# Script to copy multiple ranges to another sheet (Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Pretty new to coding and I've been trying to solve this one, but I can't find out how and now I'm turing to you guys:

There is a spec sheet, containing a couple of information on an item:
Product Name (on A3)
Product Code (on A4)
Volume (on c3)
Und (on C4)
Cost (on A5), etc.

Then, underneath this "header", there is a table containing the ingredients that make up that item:
**ItemNumber, Product, Manufacturer, Unt, Cost, Remarks**
These are set on a range (A12:T50)

The need is to have this table moved to a sheet, which the below code does, but how I can I have the header moved as well, repeating each of the header ranges, forming a database-like table for further consulting?

Here is the working script:

```
function copyrange() { 
  var sourceSheet = 'New Item';
  var destinationSheet = 'Consolidated';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
  var LastRowSource = sheet.getLastRow();
  var LastColumnSource = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var values = sheet.getRange(11,1,LastRowSource,LastColumnSource).getValues();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet); 
  var data = []; 
  var j =[]; 

  for (var i = values.length-1; i != ""; i--) {
    if ( values[i][0] != '') { 
      data.push(values[i]);
      //sheet.deleteRow(i+1)
    } 
  } 
  //Copy data array to destination sheet 
  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); 
}
```

Here is the link to the file in question:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GlD_VIOFHj7PGfCCnfVZqdZbE22aVoUw91BSCZecsRc/edit#gid=371161645

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is `there is a table containing the ingredients that make up that item: ItemNumber, Product, Manufacturer, Unt, Cost, Remarks These are set on a range (A12:T50)`? 2. What is `a database-like table for further consulting`?

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike!
I'm the one to apologize for not making myself clear enough!
The document is of a product. Some of this product's information is on the header in different columns and rows and its composition is on a table, on a set range, underneath the header. Now I need a table consolidating both the composition and the header information and I can't combine these through a script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still see the vision of your situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, Here is the link to the spreadsheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GlD_VIOFHj7PGfCCnfVZqdZbE22aVoUw91BSCZecsRc/edit?usp=sharing
Basically, the script has to bring both the Product Chocolate1 and its details to the other sheet, as well as this item's composition, which is in a table below. See the example I made manually on the ArquivoItens highlighted in blue. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, from your sample Spreadsheet and your question, I couldn't understand what you want to do. When I could correctly understand about your goal, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize for my poor understanding.

Comment: The table you describe in your question and the spreadsheet you have provided don't seem to match up... also, what do you mean by `repeating header information`? Why do you need this more than one time in your second sheet? Is freezing the first row not a viable solution if this is for visibility?

Comment: Hello @RafaGuillermo,
Thanks for reponding!
The second spreadsheet must store all information from the first sheet. Since I got the table containing the materiais listed, the header information should fulfill the other columns, so that I can filter them later, using it as a database.